# Django wrong url resolve - leads to example.com

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to reverse url for django admin "view on site button". 
My route

```
(r'^product/(?P<num>.*)/(?P<url>.*)/$', set),
```

Models get_absolute_url method looks fine:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('core.views.set', kwargs={'num': self.url_num, 'url': self.url})
```

SO, it should be like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/97/n3/`
But when it rendered in django admin form, it is `http://example.com/product/97/n3/`

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is your version of django? `set` is a built-in - best to avoid it as a name.

Comment: I've shortened real param to 'set' for simplification. Django 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django takes domain name for get_absolute_url from system table "django_site". You can modify it from admin or through database console. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.models.Site

Comment: As you can see from the OP, the domain name from sites is not used, because they provided their own `get_absolute_url`.